# How to build FLTK as a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, build, msys2, fltk

My environment is: MinGW, MSYS2, WINDOWS 10

For building [FLTK 1.3.5](https://www.fltk.org/) in my envirmoment, the official instruction(file `README.MSWindows.txt`) describes the following steps:

1. `open mingw64.exe`
2. `cd 'to fltk source code directory'`
3. `.\configure`
4. `make`(In my case `make` not working, I just typing `mingw32-make`)

On my computer, the build completes successfully, but this script does not generate a .dll files. From this we can conclude that the compiled library is meant to be *statically linked*. I tried `.\configure --shared-library` but it didn't give the desired effect. The instruction can answer this question but for Visual C6. It not my case, I prefer Codelite and MinGW.

What steps should I follow to get a FLTK designed for *dynamic linking*?

Comment: From the source code it looks like if you use CMake to generate your makefile you have the option of building a shared library. https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Comment: I just attempted this however my gcc version (10.2) from msys2 was too new for the 1.3.5 sources.

Comment: @drescherjm You provided a link from the repository FLTK 1.4.0(https://github.com/fltk/fltk/blob/master/VERSION). My question is actual for stable version(1.3.5)

Comment: 1.3.5 also has a CMakeLists.txt with the shared option. I know that because I enabled building shared libs. However since my installed mingw has gcc version 10.2 I had errors building: `C:/msys64/home/dresc/fltk-1.3.5/fluid/ExternalCodeEditor_WIN32.cxx:141:13: error: narrowing conversion of '-1' from 'int' to 'long unsigned int' [-Wnarrowing]
  141 |       case -1:  // error
      |             ^`

Comment: I see that bug was reported here: [https://www.fltk.org/newsgroups.php?s1728+gfltk.issues+v1729](https://www.fltk.org/newsgroups.php?s1728+gfltk.issues+v1729)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not good at building libraries, but I attempt to add `set(OPTION_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS,1)` in `fltk-1.3.5/CMakeLists.txt`. I am currently waiting for the build to finish

Comment: I used ccmake to enable `OPTION_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`

Comment: Habe you tried `./configure --enable-shared`?

Comment: @ssbssa it looks odd but dll's files are still not generated